# Is the format of the data held in kotlin.MetaData documented anywhere?

Tags: kotlin

I'm interested to know what data is held in the MetaData annotation added to each Kotlin class.

But most fields give no more detail than

*"Metadata in a custom format. The format may be different (or even absent) for different kinds."*

https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/jvm/runtime/kotlin/Metadata.kt

Is there are reference somewhere that explains how to interpret this data?

Comment: `Metadata` stores all the information as an encoded protobuf. Its scheme can be found in the [official repository](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/ee50aec7342ab375a105bb318e6501135e859028/core/deserialization/src/descriptors.proto). There is no official API for reading that information at the moment, but it's still accessible using [internal APIs](https://gist.github.com/nsk-mironov/8c9c3092e9844233cdbb).

Comment: @VladimirMironov what about full answer instead comment? Because you quite right, afaik.

Comment: @IRus I'd rather wait for an answer from [Alexander Udalov](http://stackoverflow.com/users/288456/alexander-udalov)

Comment: The official API for reading that information is the Kotlin reflection API. Not sure why you'd want to have a lower-level access to the data.

Comment: @VladimirMironov Not worked through it yet but it looks like your link has all the info I need. I you post it as an answer I'll accept. Thanks.

Comment: @yole The reflection API isn't available when you're analyzing classes at compile time via kapt.

Comment: The link has moved: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/jvm/runtime/kotlin/Metadata.kt

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`kotlin.Metadata` contains information about Kotlin symbols, such as their names, signatures, relations between types, etc. Some of this information is already present in the JVM signatures in the class files, but a lot is not, since there's quite a few Kotlin-specific things which JVM class files cannot represent properly: type nullability, mutable/read-only collection interfaces, declaration-site variance, and others.

No specific actions were taken to make the schema of the data encoded in this annotation public, because for most users such data is needed to introspect a program at runtime, and the [Kotlin reflection library](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html) provides a nice API for that.

If you need to inspect Kotlin-specific stuff which is not exposed via the reflection API, or you're just generally curious what else is stored in that annotation, you can take a look at the implementation of [kotlinx.reflect.lite](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.reflect.lite). It's a light-weight library, the core of which is the protobuf-generated schema parser. There's not much supported there at the moment, but there are [schemas](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.reflect.lite/tree/master/src) available
which you can use to read any other data you need.

UPD (August 2018): since this was answered, we've published a new (experimental and unstable) library, which is designed to be the intended way for reading and modifying the metadata: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/announcing-kotlinx-metadata-jvm-library-for-reading-modifying-metadata-of-kotlin-jvm-class-files/7980