# Why does Kotlin hold MetaData in Kotlin class file?

Tags: metadata, kotlin

We converted a Java file to Kotlin file, and then compiled to class file. The resulting class is bigger than the original Java class file. In the Kotlin class file, we found metadata in every class. Why does Kotlin store this metadata?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the format of the data held in kotlin.MetaData documented anywhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816521/is-the-format-of-the-data-held-in-kotlin-metadata-documented-anywhere)

Comment: Thanks. But I still wonder if  Meatadata is useful in runtime.@PixelElephant

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some aspects of code in Kotlin cannot be expressed in pure Java bytecode (e.g. nullability, primary constructors, `internal` visibility, `lateinit` modifier, properties delegation and more). Instead, they are serialized and stored as metadata in the classes.

When you use a JAR distribution of a Kotlin library, the compiler parses the metadata to discover these Kotlin specific attributes in order to use the library as a Kotlin artifact with all the features available.

At runtime, the metadata is used by `kotlin-reflect`, the Kotlin reflection API, to reconstruct these attributes and provide access to them through reflection.

Comment: Thanks for your response! As google's suggestion, kotlin will be more populor in Android development. But the kotlin class file‘s size is nearly twice than normal java class file's size, so the kotlin apk will be more and more bigger. I don't know Jetbrains and google how to fix it. @hotkey

Comment: @TonyChou if you don't use runtime Kotlin reflection, you can use Proguard (or other tools) to strip the `@kotlin.Metadata` annotations from the apk