# How to interpret kotlin's @Metadata annotation content?

Tags: annotations, kotlin

I know that kotlin generates @Metadata annotation for each compiled class. I also saw the comment on this type:

*This annotation is present on any class file produced by the Kotlin compiler and is read by the compiler and reflection.*

The question is how it is used by the compiler(assuming that it's a result of compilation)?

And I'll ask help with interpretation of content of the annotation. For example, this one:

```
@Metadata(
   mv = {1, 1, 9},
   bv = {1, 0, 2},
   k = 1,
   d1 = {"\u0000\f\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u0000\n\u0002\b\u0003\u0018\u0000 \u00032\u00020\u0001:\u0001\u0003B\u0005¢\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0002¨\u0006\u0004"},
   d2 = {"LMain;", "", "()V", "Companion", "production sources for module kotlin-examples"}
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should read the rest of the comments in the [source](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/runtime.jvm/src/kotlin/Metadata.kt) of the annotation and check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36816521/4465208).

Comment: still no anwser ?

Comment: May be this helps you: kotlinx-metadata-jvm library for reading/modifying metadata of Kotlin/JVM class files

https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/announcing-kotlinx-metadata-jvm-library-for-reading-modifying-metadata-of-kotlin-jvm-class-files/7980